# Lest we forget, many large conflicts (have) started over small, insignificant areas

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-simple

[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lest-we-forget):
**(1)** *Lest we forget, many large conflicts **have started** over small, insignificant areas*.
my variant:
**(2)** *Lest we forget, many large conflicts **started** over small, insignificant areas*.

The conflicts the sentence is about happened sometime in the past and, therefore, do not relate to the present. That means, we must use (2) rather than (1).

Why is the usage of the present perfect correct?
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Its just the usual past/perfect difference.  Whether you want to make the connection to the present is a matter of choice.  "many conflicts have started over small areas, so we should be aware of the dangers of starting a conflict in this area"  That is a clear connection to the present.

Comment: How did you decide that events in the past don't relate to the present? Sentence (1) sounds like a warning in the present, especially when it starts with "lest we forget".